# How do I fix an error code that wont let me install or update anything?

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

This is the message that displays every time I try to update or install anything:

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
298 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/25.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 109 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 162877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:amd64 (1.3-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_am
d64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg', which is different from ot
her instances of package libvdpau1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```output of ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
````

Comment: "298 not fully installed or removed" means a seriously broken package management.

Comment: what are my recommended options?

Comment: Any such recommendations are above my pay grade.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: It did not work. Went down that rabbit hole and tried all the commands i could find. Still unsuccessful so far. Still looking though thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall libvdpau1
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Explanation:

1. `apt clean` - Clean the download packages cache; this will cause the package files to be downloaded again.
2. `apt update` - Update the database that stores the list of software packages
3. `apt install --reinstall libvdpau1` reinstall the package `libvdpau1` that seems to be causing your issues
4. `apt --fix-broken install` - Attempt to correct broken dependencies

Comment: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8)manpageforrepositorycreationanduserconfigurationdetails.

Comment: this message is what i got

Comment: OK. I think I see what is going on. Please edit your question and add the output of `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Also, I would remove libvdpau1 temporarily and try to get everything working with "dpkg --configure" and "apt --fix-broken". You might want to remove it with:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libvdpau1
```

This is to prevent removing anything else. Note that this will temporarily leave your package system in a broken state if there are packages that depend on libvdpau1, but your package system is in a broken state already.

Once you get things working, try reinstalling it.

The error about the Gnome PPA missing a release file seems unrelated to your current problem. It is probably due having activated a PPA after an update to a newer version (Focal) and the PPA not being configured to that new version. In general, using a PPA for something like Gnome that is an integral part of the system is not a great idea, but I digress. You should fix your /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: When I try that second command I get this warning. (dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libvdpau1:amd64, only the config
 files of which are on the system; use --purge to remove them too)

Comment: I'd recommend that you just add the --purge to it. That way you'll get the broken package out of your system.